# Android: TextView.setTextAppearance() does not effect text size

Tags: android

Running on my Samsung Galaxy Note, the below code logs 28.0 for each log statement.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
label = new TextView(context);
Log.e("text size", "" + label.getTextSize());

label.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
Log.e("text size", "" + label.getTextSize());

label.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.attr.textAppearanceSmall);
Log.e("text size", "" + label.getTextSize());
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the `style` class, not `attr`.

```
label.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

This same point of confusion was reported here: [TextView.setTextAppearance not working](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1727).

Comment: @TorbenKohlmeier Why API level 14 ?

Comment: @AsafK I have really no idea why I posted that... API level 14 is not required...